# Tkinter Python / tk - Affecting other widgets of tkinter and same class object

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

MY CODE :

Here's the output in OOP way:

You can see the 2nd object's entry field changed automatically without any reason. I dont want it to be changed.

[image]

When I run this code both objects of Entry2 Class don't work properly as I wanted.
Where am I doing mistake . I hope this is clear for you to understand what i want.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

#"""
#Orange Theme
bgcolor =       "#ef6c45"
bgcolor2 =      "#fcf0e2"
textcolor =     "#8e5541"
tabcolor =      "#F6E8D5"
#"""

root.config(bg=bgcolor)
root.geometry("250x200")
Dname = StringVar()
dname = StringVar()
#Label For root
Label(root,bg=bgcolor2).place(x=3,y=3,height=194,width=244)
#Class for creating a unique entry
class Entry2(Label):
    def __init__(self,perant,var,text,x,y,h,w,*args,**kwargs):
        Label.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs,bg=tabcolor) # calling Label Class
        self.text = text
        self.var = var
        self.x = x      # x-axis of obj
        self.y = y      # y-axis
        self.h = h      # height
        self.w = w      # width
        self.place(x=self.x,
                   y=self.y,
                   height=self.h,
                   width=self.w) # placing self object
        self.entry = Entry(perant,
                            bd=0,
                            font=("Helvetica",11),
                            bg=tabcolor,
                            fg=textcolor,
                            textvariable=self.var,
                            insertbackground=textcolor,
                            selectbackground=bgcolor,
                            selectforeground='white')
                            
        self.INFO = self.place_info() # Placing information of self to use it for further objects

        self.entry.place(x=int(self.INFO['x'])+2,y=int(self.INFO['y'])+13,
                         height=int(self.INFO['height'])-15,
                         width=int(self.INFO['width'])-4,
                         )
        self.label = Label(perant,bd=0,
                           # text=self.text,
                            bg=tabcolor,
                            fg=textcolor,
                            font=("Helvetica",11,'bold'),
                            anchor='w'
                            ) # Title
        self.label.place(x=int(self.INFO['x'])+2,
                         y=int(self.INFO['y'])+2,
                         width=int(self.INFO['width'])-4,
                         height=20,
                         )
        self.entry.delete(0,END)
        self.entry.insert(0,f'<{self.text}>')

        self.entry.bind("<FocusIn>",self.efi)
        self.entry.bind("<FocusOut>",self.efo)
            
    def efi(self,event): # Function for changing objects on focus in
        if self.var.get()==f"<{self.text}>":
            self.entry.delete(0,END)
            self.label.config(text="")
            self.label.config(text=self.text)
        self.config(bg=bgcolor)


    def efo(self,event): # function for changing objects on focus Out
        if self.var.get()=="":
            self.entry.delete(0,END)
            self.entry.insert(0,f"<{self.text}>")
            self.label.config(text="")
        self.config(bg=tabcolor)

name = Entry2(root,var=Dname,x=10,y=20,h=45,w=220,text='Name') # Object 1
number = Entry2(root,var=dname,x=10,y=100,h=45,w=220,text='Number') # Object 2

Button(root,text="Submit",bg=bgcolor,
        fg='white',
        activebackground=tabcolor,
        activeforeground=textcolor,
        bd=0).place(x=10,y=160,height=30,width=100) # Submit Button

Button(root,text="Cancel",bg=tabcolor,
        fg=textcolor,
        activebackground=tabcolor,
        activeforeground=textcolor,
        bd=0).place(x=130,y=160,height=30,width=100) # Cancel Button


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Matiiss now please review my code.

Comment: _But i want to make it OOP way._: so you want to transform your code from functional to object oriented? well then you have to start with watching some POOP tutorials: I suggest [this one by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc), the thing is that you can't do that without knowing basics (and I am not going to write how to convert) because **you have to first learn the basics** (I assume so because if you knew OOP already then you wouldn't ask how to "convert"), oh and also this is not a question to ask on SO

Comment: Bro please fix it i have final exam after 2 days i cant watch them now.. i have to work on other things if you can do this please do it...

Comment: Ok bro,from next time I'll post question in very understandable method. Thanks alot.

Comment: check it last time @Matiiss

Comment: change `self.config(bg=bgcolor)` in `efi()` method to `self.config(bg=tabcolor)`